# How to resize and move my image Front End Development

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend, image-resizing

I'm trying to move my image to the left and make it smaller so it takes up a certain amount of space on the left side. Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong? Would I use a float or col. I tried going to a site to change the dimensions directly but still nothing. Any Ideas? If you can provide some code that would be awesome.

[image].

**HTML**

```
<div class="content-area group section">
        
            <!-- container -->
            <div class="container">
                                        
                        <!-- row -->
                        <div class="row">
                            
                            <!-- col -->
                            <div class="col col-xs-6">
                                <img src="images/Ade_ingame_concept.png">
                            </div><!-- /col -->
                            
                        </div><!-- /row -->
                        
                    </div><!-- /col -->
                    
                    <!-- col -->
                    <div class="col col-md-4 sidebar">
                        <h3>Sidebar Heading</h3>
                    </div><!-- /col -->
                    
                </div><!-- /row -->
                
            </div><!-- /container -->
            
        </div>

        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2014 - This is the footer.</p>
        </footer>
```

**CSS**

```
 /* Main Column Typography */

.main-area h2 {
    font-size: 165%;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  
  .section {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
  }
  
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    body {
      font-size: 16px;
    }
  
    .container {
      max-width: 1200px;
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .section {
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
    }
  }
  
  header {
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: #fffff;
    background-color: #405c71;
  }
  
  header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 165%;
  }
  
  header p {
    font-size: 90%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  /* Site Navigation */
  .site-nav {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  
  .site-nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .site-nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  
  .site-nav a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #365267;
  }
  
  .site-nav a:hover {
    background-color: #2c465a;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .site-nav li {
      width: 33.332%;
      margin-right: 0;
    }
  
    .site-nav a {
      padding: 15px 0;
      margin-right: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .site-nav li {
      width: 50%;
    }
  }
  
  /* End Site Navigation */
  
  .content-area {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-top: 40px;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .content-area {
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
  }
  
  .main-area {
    width: 66%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .sidebar {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 85%;
  }
  
  .sidebar h3 {
    font-size: 138.5%;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
  }
  
  .info-box {
    background-color: #efeedb;
    border: 5px solid #e6e5c2;
    padding: 20px 40px 7px 40px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .hide-small {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  
  .box-a {
    background-color: #e7eff5;
    padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
    border: 2px solid #d3dee7;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .box-a {
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
  }
  
  /* Grid */
  .row {
    margin-right: -20px;
  }
  
  .col {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .col-xs-11 {
    width: 91.662%;
  }
  .col-xs-10 {
    width: 83.332%;
  }
  .col-xs-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-xs-8 {
    width: 66.662%;
  }
  .col-xs-7 {
    width: 58.331%;
  }
  .col-xs-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-xs-5 {
    width: 41.662%;
  }
  .col-xs-4 {
    width: 33.332%;
  }
  .col-xs-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-xs-2 {
    width: 16.662%;
  }
  .col-xs-1 {
    width: 8.332%;
  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .row {
      margin-right: -40px;
    }
  
    .col {
      padding-right: 40px;
    }
  
    .col-sm-11 {
      width: 91.662%;
    }
    .col-sm-10 {
      width: 83.332%;
    }
    .col-sm-9 {
      width: 75%;
    }
    .col-sm-8 {
      width: 66.662%;
    }
    .col-sm-7 {
      width: 58.331%;
    }
    .col-sm-6 {
      width: 50%;
    }
    .col-sm-5 {
      width: 41.662%;
    }
    .col-sm-4 {
      width: 33.332%;
    }
    .col-sm-3 {
      width: 25%;
    }
    .col-sm-2 {
      width: 16.662%;
    }
    .col-sm-1 {
      width: 8.332%;
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .col-md-11 {
      width: 91.662%;
    }
    .col-md-10 {
      width: 83.332%;
    }
    .col-md-9 {
      width: 75%;
    }
    .col-md-8 {
      width: 66.662%;
    }
    .col-md-7 {
      width: 58.331%;
    }
    .col-md-6 {
      width: 50%;
    }
    .col-md-5 {
      width: 41.662%;
    }
    .col-md-4 {
      width: 33.332%;
    }
    .col-md-3 {
      width: 25%;
    }
    .col-md-2 {
      width: 16.662%;
    }
    .col-md-1 {
      width: 8.332%;
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    .col-lg-11 {
      width: 91.662%;
    }
    .col-lg-10 {
      width: 83.332%;
    }
    .col-lg-9 {
      width: 75%;
    }
    .col-lg-8 {
      width: 66.662%;
    }
    .col-lg-7 {
      width: 58.331%;
    }
    .col-lg-6 {
      width: 50%;
    }
    .col-lg-5 {
      width: 41.662%;
    }
    .col-lg-4 {
      width: 33.332%;
    }
    .col-lg-3 {
      width: 25%;
    }
    .col-lg-2 {
      width: 16.662%;
    }
    .col-lg-1 {
      width: 8.332%;
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .push-down-sm {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .push-down-sm {
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
  }
  
  footer {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 85%;
    color: #fff;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  
  .row:before,
  .row:after,
  .group:before,
  .group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
  }
  
  .row:after,
  .group:after {
    clear: both;
  }
  
  .row,
  .group {
    zoom: 1;
  }
```

Comment: Where is your CSS that you are using to change the display of the image? If you don't show us your code, we can't help fix it!

Comment: I still don't see any CSS for the image... where did you include it and what rules were you trying to sue? That's what we need to see, because that is what you are having problems with.

Comment: I added the changes, and I'm trying to have the image fit within a column without shrinking the image.

Comment: If you don't want to shrink the image, then why are you setting the `height:50` in your CSS? The reason it isn't in your column is probably because your HTML is invalid - see my answer below - but it's difficult to know what you are trying to do because your title says you *do* want to resize the image!

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I set the height to 50 because I was trying to fit the image into the container. I asked to re size the image because my image was not fitting within the column. Also I'm not/wasn't using bootstrap.

Comment: If you're not using bootstrap, what at the `container`, `row` and `col` elements? You didn't include the CSS for those in your code either... are you using another grid framework? What *exactly* are you trying to achieve? Is it like my updated answer but without bootstrap?

Comment: I'm trying to do it with like your answer without bootstrap. Except my image is very large. I added my complete CSS.

Comment: Whether you are using bootstrap CSS or your own CSS, then the result should be the same as in my answer - you just have your HTML wrong. For example you are closing `col`s that you don't open in the code. Make your HTML look more like the structure in my answer and it should work - that would be a starting point and you can try add whatever other rows/cols you need then.

Comment: @Masterolu Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?

Comment: Thank you everyone but I figured it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Masterolu I wanted to know whether my solution helped you or you did it by yourself. If you did it by yourself, can you tell me how you did it, I would love to know how you resolved your issue.

Comment: If you solved the problem yourself, please post the solution as an answer here so that this question is helpful for other users with similar problems, and so that the question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 img {
    margin:0 30px 0 0; //choose your value
    display:block
    width:100%;
max-width:100%;
    height: auto;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this shrinks the image. I want the image to the maximum size within a column.

Comment: Ok, try with this

Comment: microb14, you'd be better off spending time on your own question :) We still don't have the information we need to be able to help you.

Comment: @FluffyKitten you made my day on my own question. Thank you

Comment: No the image still stays in place

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left;` to align image to left.

Use **Viewport Units** like **vm** or **vh** instead of **px** or **%** for sizing your image, text and every other element because it will help you make your webpage/website responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `height:50` is invalid CSS - you need to include a unit, e.g. `50px`

Also, your HTML code is invalid, so I've tried to piece together what I could from it to recreate the row and col you have included.

If this isn't want you want, then can you clarify your question and include the code you **are** using?

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="content-area group section">

  <!-- container -->
  <div class="container">

    <!-- row -->
    <div class="row">

      <!-- col -->
      <div class="col-6">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/P59NF.png">
      </div>
      <!-- /col -->

      <!-- col -->
      <div class="col-4 sidebar">
        <h3>Sidebar Heading</h3>
      </div>
      <!-- /col -->

    </div><!-- /row -->
  </div><!-- /container -->
</div><!-- /div.content-area -->
```

Image without CSS:

[image]

**Update:**

Now you say you *don't* want to resize the image (even though your title says you do), so then you just need to fix your HTML so the `cols` and `row`s are right, e.g.

```
<!-- row -->
<div class="row">

  <!-- col -->
  <div class="col-6">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/P59NF.png">
  </div>
  <!-- /col -->

  <!-- col -->
  <div class="col-4 sidebar">
    <h3>Sidebar Heading</h3>
  </div>
  <!-- /col -->

</div>
<!-- /row -->
```